# how to send value to the from action page from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a faq panel for there can be multiple answers for question and i want to take the answer id .because i am storing comment by answer id

the problem is that how to sent the $answer_id to the  comment_submit_process.php and how to recognize the answer ?

```
$selected_ques= mysql_prep($_GET['ques']);
   $query = "SELECT * FROM formanswer where question_id = {$selected_ques}";
    $ans=  mysql_query($query);
    if($ans){
       while($answer = mysql_fetch_array($ans))  

           //here is the form  
        <form id="add-comment" action="comment_submit_process.php" >
         <textarea   class="comment-submit-textarea" cols="78" name="comment" style="height: 64px;"></textarea>
         <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Add Comment" class="comment-submit-button"  >

         <br> <?php
         $ans_id= $answer['id'];  //i am fatching the $answer['id'] from database

         ?>

            <input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $_GET['$ans_id'] ?>" />
         <span class="counter ">enter at least 15 characters</span>
         <span class="form-error"></span>
     </form>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: is it not in the hidden form field named "ques" ?

Comment: @Dagon sir its showing error undefined index $ans_id

Comment: in your input type hidden shouldn't it be $_GET['ans_id']. Remove $ from $_GET

Comment: shouldn't $ans_id= $answer['id']; be $ans_id= $_GET['$ans_id']; and you use the %_GET version in the hidden form field anyway

Comment: @Dagon i am fatching the $answer['id'] from database

Comment: You might have typo here !!
 it should be..
 `<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $ans_id; ?>" />`

Other thing, you can add get param to action link it self.
 `<form id="add-comment" action="comment_submit_process.php?<?php echo  $answer['id']; ?>" >`

Comment: @Mayankswami : I have written in Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have typo here !! it should be..

```
<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $ans_id; ?>" />
```

Other thing, you can add get param to action link it self.

```
<form id="add-comment" action="comment_submit_process.php?<?php echo $answer['id']; ?>" >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can echo answer_id in form action tag as additional parameter like this:

```
<form id="add-comment" action="comment_submit_process.php?ans_id=$ans_id" >

//Your stuff here

</form>
```

in comment_submit_process.php you can identify answer by

```
$ans_id=$_GET['ans_id'];
```

You can do further processing by using $ans_id

**Edit:**
change this line:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $_GET['$ans_id'] ?>"
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ques" value="<?php echo $ans_id; ?>" />
```

so that value of that field would be $ans_id fetched from DB.

Comment: this is the simplest way. you also can put answer_id in input field with type hidden and grab it in comment_submit_process.php

Comment: undefined index $ans_id in $_GET means either $ans_id is not initialized or it should be $_GET['ans_id']. tell me from where exactly you want to fetcg ans_id from sql or $_GET. make sure sql and $_GET have the proper values

Comment: See the EDIT of my answer.
<br /> was accident :D :D :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the ans_id, every time to the hidden field .
Generate a string of ans_id seperated with "," until while loop ends append the string  and assign that value to the hidden field and in form action page you can get that value and generate van array from that string with delimiter ",".Now you can have the array of ans_id in your form action page

```
      $answer_array = "nothing";
     while($answer = mysql_fetch_array($ans))
      {
         if( $answer_array == "nothing")
               $answer_array = $answer;
         else
             $answer_array .= ",".$answer;
       }
      <input type="hidden" name="answer_arr" value="<?=$answer_array?>">
```

In Form action page you can get that hidden value

```
     $ans_array= explode(",",$_GET['answer_arr']);
```

Comment: i am doing every thing in the while loop so i can not close it because i have to show many answer

Comment: No problem what every code you would like to put in while put it but don't include the hidden field and form in the while loop